# Concatenate one-to-many field in single result?

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, syntax, group-concatenation

Say I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM AppDetails, AppTags 
WHERE AppDetails.AppID = '1' 
  AND AppDetails.AppID = AppTags.AppID
```

Which gives the following results:

```
AppID    AppName        AppType    Tag
1        Application1   Utility    Test1
1        Application1   Utility    Test2
1        Application1   Utility    Test3
```

How can I modify the query to return something like this:

```
AppID    AppName        AppType    Tags
1        Application1   Utility    Test1,Test2,Test3
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately SQL Server doesn't have an single function to perform group concatenation but there are a few different ways that you can get the result.

You can implement [`FOR XML PATH`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx) and [`STUFF()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.AppId,
  d.AppName,
  d.AppType,
  Tags = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t.TagName
                FROM AppTags t
                where d.AppID = t.AppID
                FOR XML PATH (''))
                , 1, 1, '') 
FROM AppDetails d
WHERE d.AppID = '1';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/257c7/5).

Or you could use `FOR XML PATH` with `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.AppId,
  d.AppName,
  d.AppType,
  tags = left(t.tags, len(t.tags)-1) 
FROM AppDetails d
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT t.TagName + ', '
  FROM AppTags t
  WHERE d.AppID = t.AppID
  FOR XML PATH('')
) t (Tags)
WHERE d.AppID = '1';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/257c7/6).

If you want to then query against the `tags` values, then you can use a CTE similar to:

```
;with cte as
(
  SELECT DISTINCT d.AppId,
    d.AppName,
    d.AppType,
    Tags = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t.TagName
                  FROM AppTags t
                  where d.AppID = t.AppID
                  FOR XML PATH (''))
                  , 1, 1, '') 
  FROM AppDetails d
  WHERE d.AppID = '1'
)
select *
from cte
where tags like '%test1%'
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/257c7/8)

If `TagName` includes certain XML characters (e.g. `>`, `&`) they will become entitized (`>` -> `&gt;`, `&` -> `&amp;`). To avoid this, change `FOR XML PATH('')` to `FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')`.