# Join one-to-many field in a single result without concatenation

Tags: sql-server, query, pivot

I suffer from the same problem as in [Concatenate one-to-many field in single result?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50153/concatenate-one-to-many-field-in-single-result), but I need a result where the 'many' fields occupy their own columns and aren't concatenated in one column. Any suggestions?

Sample data:

```
___ID      Mapped_Heading    Source_Value
1          English           pass
1          Math              pass
1          History           fail


___ID      Name              Age
1          Bob               12
2          Harry             12
3          Emily             14
```

And the End result would be:

```
___ID      Name      Age  English   Math   History
1          Bob       12   pass      pass   fail
```

I was hoping I wouldn't have to use `PIVOT` and `PARTITION BY` because I'm not familiar with those functions, but I keep bumping into them for this problem so think I might have to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way you can do this is with a `PIVOT`.

Here is the setup code:

```sql
create table grades (
  ID             int,
  Mapped_Heading varchar(10),
  Source_Value   varchar(10)
);
create table students (
  ID   int,
  Name varchar(10),
  Age  int
);
insert grades 
values
(1,'English', 'pass'),
(1,'Math',    'pass'),
(1,'History', 'fail');
insert students
values
(1, 'Bob',   12),
(2, 'Harry', 12),
(3, 'Emily', 14);
```

Here is the `PIVOT` code:

```sql
with temp as (
  select s.*, g.Mapped_Heading, g.Source_Value
  from students s
  join grades g on g.ID = s.ID
)
select * 
from (
    select * 
    from temp
) a
pivot (
    max(Source_Value)
    for Mapped_Heading in ([English],[Math],[History])
) as b
```

The output looks like this:

```
+----+------+-----+---------+------+---------+
| ID | Name | Age | English | Math | History |
+----+------+-----+---------+------+---------+
| 1  | Bob  | 12  | pass    | pass | fail    |
+----+------+-----+---------+------+---------+
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5ef0d415be4d6e09450254b6f0fc6655)

Comment: I am extremely grateful. This worked perfectly as described and has really helped me.